# c++ template class pass constructor by ref depending on type

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, metaprogramming, sfinae

Let's say I have a class which looks like this which should either be constructed by value if `T` is a simple type like `double` or by reference if `T` is more complex.

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
template<class T>
class Val {
  public:
    Val() = default;
    Val(double v) : _v(v) {}

    template<typename U = T>
    Val(const &T v,
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U,double>::value, bool>::type = 0)
    : _v(v) {}
  private:
    T _v;
};
```

Which works, but feels really sketchy, since an additional parameter is introduced into the constructor. Is there a better solution to this problem? It seems like this would be better suited for an overload or template specialization solution? Can this be solved generally for all simple types (`int`, `float`, `double`...)?

Comment: Unless the constructor is so complex that it can't be inlined, I doubt that passing by value/reference makes a difference for "simple types". This really sounds like unnecessary micro-optimization to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to have one constructor. It, after all, does the same thing in both cases right? First, define a type trait which, based on `T`, is either a value or reference:

```
template <typename T>
using param_type = std::conditional_t<
                       is_complex_type<T>::value,
                       T const&,
                       T>;
```

Where `is_complex_type` is some appropriate type trait to be determined later. Maybe it's `is_fundamental` as other answers proposed.

And then just use it:

```
template<class T>
class Val {
public:
    Val() = default;
    Val(param_type<T> v) : _v(v) { }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

There is `std::is_fundamental` which should fit you. Best looking solution for me is:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_fundamental<T>::value >::type func(T p_arg){}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_fundamental<T>::value >::type func(T const &p_arg){}
```

Comment: But this won't work for constructors, since they do not have a return type?

Comment: in this case you can use default template parameter

Answer (score 2):

Just a little modified version of your code along with CyberGuy's recommendation of [`std::is_fundamental`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental) will do what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Val
{
public:
    template <typename U = T>
    Val(T v,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<U>::value>::type* = 0)
        : _v(v)
    {
        cout << "fundamental" << endl;
    }

    template <typename U = T>
    Val(T const& v,
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<U>::value>::type* = 0)
        : _v(v)
    {
        cout << "complex" << endl;
    }

private:
    T _v;
};

struct A {};

int main()
{
    Val<double> v1(1);
    Val<char> v2('a');
    Val<A> v3(A{});
}
```

Output:

```
fundamental
fundamental
complex
```

Comment: yes, the even better one or more clear is to use default template parameter

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`boost::call_traits<T>::param_type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm)

```
template<class T>
class Val {
  public:
    Val() = default;
    Val(boost::call_traits<T>::param_type v) : _v(v) {}
  private:
    T _v;
};
```